# co_await not working

Tags: c++, uwp

I attempted to try out `co_await` as mentioned in this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/04/using-c-coroutines-to-simplify-async-uwp-code/ but there are weird compilation errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44,0): Error C2825: '_Ret': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44): error C2825: '_Ret': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp) 
MainPage.xaml.cpp(44): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::experimental::coroutine_traits<void,::MainPage ^,Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs ^>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44,0): Error C2510: '_Ret': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44): error C2510: '_Ret': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44,0): Error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'promise_type' (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'promise_type' (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\experimental\resumable(44,0): Error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file MainPage.xaml.cpp)
```

Originally, I put the following code in the constructor

```
#include <experimental\resumable>
#include <pplawait.h>

using namespace concurrency;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    auto my_data_file = co_await Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync("samples.txt");

    // Preparing app data structures
}
```

which does not work. My guess is that this is not possible in constructor (for obvious reason) so I move the `co_await` line to

```
void MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto my_data_file = co_await Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync("samples.txt");
}
```

which result in the aforementioned compilation errors.

Comment: Did you turn on the feature in the compiler? What code are you getting these compile errors on? Do those types even have `await` machinery? Provide a full example that you believe should work which does not.

Comment: @NicolBolas I already added `/await` compilation option.

Comment: And what of the rest of my questions? I don't see a [mcve] anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the first problem is that you can't return `void` from a resumable function since `void` does not fill any coroutine traits that `co_await` expect (like `get_return_object` , `set_result` etc.)

if you are already using PPL, return `task<void>`:

```
task<void> MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto my_data_file = co_await Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync("samples.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: `co_await` can <del>only be used if we are returning a `task<>`</del> (this is incorrect, see @DavidHaim's answer). I guess it is just a syntactic sugar for `create_task`. The solution is to extract a method returning `task<void>` in this case:

```
#include <experimental\resumable>
#include <pplawait.h>

using namespace concurrency;

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PrepareData();
}

task<void> MainPage::PrepareData()
{
     auto my_data_file = co_await Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation->GetFileAsync("samples.txt");

     // Preparing app data structures
}
```

**Some comment**: Although the coroutine feature looks nice, it pollutes the language. Observe that the body of `PrepareData()` does NOT have any `return` statement but the signature says it returns `task<void>`, leading to my failure to recognize the requirement in the article.

Comment: not only I already answered you and you should accept my answer, you answer is also incorrect. you can return from a resumable function anything that supplies coroutine traits. not only `task<>`

Comment: @DavidHaim Already accepted your answer. I didn't know that since I quoted the information from the article in my question: "With Coroutines, we can use co_await in C++, but we *still need to be* in a task, so the code could be written like this:" leading to my interpretation that `task<>` is required.